# C++: Strange math results

Tags: c++, math

The following calculation results in "1" for me.

```
unsigned long iEndFrame = ((4294966336 + 1920 - 1) / 1920) + 1;
```

Does anybody see why?  I thought that `unsigned long` could handle this.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: If you need a real number output, you've to make one of the operands `double` or `float`. Just change this to `double iEndFrame = ((4294966336 + 1920 - 1) / 1920.0) + 1;`.

Comment: Use `4294966336UL`.

Comment: What compiler are you using? And are you really compiling it in C++ mode? Or C mode by any chance?

Comment: Note also that a modern C++ compiler (C++11) will produce `2236963`, not `1` as the result of that expression, so specifying the version of the language you are trying to use is important.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The values on the right of your calculation have type `unsigned int` or `int`.

```
4294966336 + 1920 = 4294968256
```

assuming `sizeof(unsigned int) == 4`, this overflows, leaving you with `960`

```
(960-1)/1920 = 0
```

(due to rounding in integer arithmetic).  This leaves you with

```
0 + 1 = 1
```

If you want to perform the calculation using a larger type (and assuming that `sizeof(unsigned long) > sizeof(unsigned int)`), you need a cast inside the calculation

```
unsigned long iEndFrame = (((unsigned long)4294966336 + 1920 - 1) / 1920) + 1;
```

or, as noted by Slava, set one of the literal values to have `unsigned long` type using the `UL` suffix

```
unsigned long iEndFrame = ((4294966336UL + 1920 - 1) / 1920) + 1;
```

Comment: Why not 4294966336UL or 4294966336ul ?

Comment: Should that be `(960-1)/1920`?

Comment: `sizeof` does not count bits.

Comment: That's wrong reasoning. A compliant C++ compiler is not allowed to use `unsigned int` to represent the values on the right hand side of that expression. Only *signed* types can be used. The only compiler that would be allowed to use unsigned types, is C compiler from C89/90 era. But C++ compiler were never allowed to do that.

Comment: @simonc Why does it still gives me 1? and sizeof(unsigned long) gives 4...I'm lost :(

Comment: @Memo It looks like `sizeof(unsigned long)==4` for your system. You could try using `uint64_t` instead, including `<cstdint>` for access to it

Comment: ... which means that the real answer to the original question in the realm of C++ language is: due to the lack of sufficiently large signed type the program has *undefined behavior*. That's what produced that `1`. Everything else is just attempts to "disassemble" and "rationalize" undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndreyT: +1 In GCC 4.8.1, with `-std=c++03` I get, warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90; with `-std=c++11` it compiles normally, with no cast/literal suffix on the RHS of the expr. and I get the expected result.

Comment: @legends2k: That's exactly what I'm talking about. And in C++11 this code will produce `2236963`, as it should, since `long long int` becomes available to the compiler. The answer above would only apply to C90. But as a C++ answer it is plainly incorrect, or, more precisely, nothing more that pointless musings about the inner workings of some specific manifestation of UB.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks, that was an incomplete edit from taking about 32-bit to `sizeof`.  Now fixed.

Comment: @AndreyT: Say in such situations, if C++03 is what I'm allowed to use, then my only option to represent such numbers beyond `unsigned long` is to resort to a big number library?

Comment: @legends2k: This is not really related to the issue in question,. But your options also include using any implementation-specific extended types. Even if you are using C++03, your implementation can still support `long long` or, say, `int128_t`. But if you have to write absolutely formally portable C++03 code (if there's such a thing), then yes, unsigned long is the widest integer one. After that you have to use a library.

Answer (score 3):

"I thought that unsigned long could handle this." - I'm not sure what you mean by this. There's nothing in the expression that you evaluate that would suggest that it should use `unsigned long`. The fact that you eventually initialize an `unsigned long` variable with it has no effect on the process of evaluation. The initializing expression is handled completely independently from that.

Now, in C++ language an unsuffixed decimal integral literal always has *signed* type. The compiler is not allowed to choose unsigned types for any of the literals used in your expression. The compiler is required to use either `int`, `long int` or `long long int` (the last one - in C++11), depending on the value of the literal. The compiler is allowed to use implementation-dependent *extended* integral types, but only if they are *signed*. And if all signed types are too small, the behavior of your program is undefined.

If we assume that we are working with typical real-life platforms with integer types having the "traditional" 16, 32 or 64 bits in width, then there are only two possibilities here

- If on your platform all signed integer types are too small to represent `4294966336`, then your program has *undefined behavior*. End of story.
- If at least one signed integer type is large enough for `4294966336`, there should be no evaluation overflow and your expression should evaluate to `2236963`.

So, the only real language-level explanation for that `1` result is that you are running into undefined behavior, because all signed types are too small to represent the literals you used in your expression.

If on your platform some signed integer type is actually sufficiently large to represent `4294966336` (i.e. some type has at least 64 bits), then the result can only be explained by the fact the your compiler is broken.

P.S. Note that the possibility of `unsigned int` being used for the evaluation only existed in old C language - C89/90. That would produce the third explanation for the result you obtained. But, again, that explanation would only apply to C89/90 compilers, not to C++ compilers or C99 compilers. And your question is tagged [C++].

Answer (score 1):

I meant to leave this as a comment, but do not have enough reputation. I wanted to share this anyway, because I think that there are two components to tmighty's question and one of them might not be answered quite correctly, from what I understand.

- First, you need to be *explicit* about the data type you are using, i.e. use a suffix such as UL or explicit type conversion. Other answers have made this clear enough, I think.
- Second, you need to then pick a data type that is large enough.

You have already stated "I thought that unsigned long could handle this" and other answers seem to confirm this, but from what I know - and double-checking just now to try to make sure - `unsigned long` may not be large enough. It is guaranteed to be at least `4294967295`, which would be too small for your use case. Specifically, I have just checked under Windows using VC++ and both compilation as 32 bit and 64 bit define ULONG_MAX to be `4294967295`.

What you may need to do instead is use the "ULL" suffix and use `unsigned long long`, since its maximum seems to be at least `18446744073709551615`. Even if there are platforms that define `unsigned long` to be large enough for your purpose, I think you might want to use a data type that is actually guaranteed to be large enough.